# Thrift Library : Usage of TServerEventHandler

Tags: thrift

I am new to Thrift , I wanted to know if there is any way i can know/differentiate between the RPC messages coming to Thrift Server and Going to Thrift Client (RPC Response)

I saw a Class TserverEventHandler.java but in that while processing request, is there a way to differentiate between the RPC Request and RPC replies

Please help me on it

Thanks in advance

Regards
Gaurav

Comment: Is that your account? http://stackoverflow.com/users/822060/gaurav-dalvi

Answer (score 1):

The event handlers support different kinds of events, and not all languages support all features yet. 
For Java, only the following events are supported:

```
public interface TServerEventHandler {

  // Called before the server begins.
  void preServe();

  // Called when a new client has connected and is about to being processing.
  ServerContext createContext(TProtocol input, TProtocol output);

  // Called when a client has finished request-handling to delete server context.
  void deleteContext(ServerContext serverContext, TProtocol input, TProtocol output);

  // Called when a client is about to call the processor.
  void processContext(ServerContext serverContext, TTransport inputTransport, TTransport outputTransport);
}
```

The Java TestServer demonstrates these handlers.

Other languages indeed support some additional events down to the detail level you want, but at this time this is **not implemented for Java**, unfortunately.